# Is there is way to display output of scala program in databricks?

Tags: python, azure, scala, databricks, azure-databricks

I was trying to run the below scala code in the azure data bricks notebook.it was running fine but not printing anything.

it just shows `defined object mainobj` after running.
How can I display output?

```
object mainobj{
  def main(args:Array[String])={
      print("Hello")
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code just defines the object `mainobj` with function `main` inside.  It doesn't execute this function.  To execute it, add a call to that function, for example, like this:

```scala
mainobj.main(Array())
```

But really, in the notebooks you don't need to wrap functions with objects - you can define them directly, like this:

```scala
def main2 = {
  print("Hello")
}
```

and just call `main2`.

Comment: Thanks for answering Alex, Here I haven't created any method to call. Here "main" is the MAIN class.

Comment: `main` also should be executed by some process, like, when you execute via `java -cp ... Main.class`. In notebooks, such thing doesn't happen automatically